# return result for i in array vs for i in array : return result

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Why doesn't this work?

```
def joining_words(train_data,reverse_word_index):
    for sequence in train_data: return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(sequence)])
    
hello = joining_words(train_data[0],reverse_word_index)
hello
```

while this does:

```
def joining_words(train_data,reverse_word_index):
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(sequence) for i in train_data])
    
hello = joining_words(train_data[0],reverse_word_index)
hello
```

Comment: Because the first function hits a `return` on the very first iteration of the loop

Comment: you're returning after the first iteration in `train_data`

Comment: When you return a value, it exits the function. Are you looking for `yield`?

Comment: The first one should return a joined **string** if exist a `value` that "*map*" in `reverse_word_index`, same for the second, but you have a nested list with all **sequences**

Answer (score 0):

Lets say when you call `reverse_word_index.get(sequence)` three times in a row you get `"a"`, `"b"`, then `"c"`. Lets look at your first statement.

#### First statement

```
for sequence in train_data:
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(sequence)])
```

On the first iteration `reverse_word_index.get(sequence)` is going to turn into `["a", "b", "c"]` so the return statement will look like:

```
return " ".join(["a"])
```

At this point the `join` will evaluate to just `"a"` and the function will return. It will never hit the second iteration because you returned *in the middle of the loop*

#### Second statement

```
def joining_words(train_data,reverse_word_index):
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(sequence) for sequence in train_data])
```

In this case `[reverse_word_index.get(sequence) for sequence in train_data]` will evaluate to `["a", "b", "c"]`. So if we substitute that back in the return statement will look like

```
return " ".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```

The `join` will evaluate to `"a b c"` and that's what the function will return.

#### Further learning

If you want to learn more about this `[foo for foo in bar]` syntax it's called a "list comprehension".